# Adding paypal form for cart screen adding three product problum with blank value

Tags: forms, paypal, cart

I am adding three item to papal cart  screen  but  if i pass the second item amount blank it only add on item first item not the third .

```
 <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="sunil-facilitator@energysinfocom.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item #1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">


<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item #2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="">


<input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Item #3">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="2.00">


<input type="submit" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

above is the form and its adding only first item i am passing the price of second blank  because that will come dynamically by check box  so it may be blank if not checked .

Any help Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a value for your item variables. If you pass a blank value, it would be ignored by PayPal (all other items after item 2 as well). Instead of passing a blank value, you can use 0 with "amount_2" variable (i.e. if checkbox is not checked, amount_2="0").

Here's an HTML example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="0">

<input type="checkbox" name="amount_2" value="1.00">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response yes i know that  but  in dynamically  in php i will use checkboxes  for the  dynamic value   so it will blank if not checked  and in that case it will not  work